# Xamarin stacking text below an image

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I am trying to figure out how to center the image and text and push the text "Cache 3" directly below the image without the bottom red space. This stacklayout is in a collection so the images are of different heights hence I can't set a HeightRequest per se.

[image]

This is my XAML:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Frame
        Margin="10"
        Padding="0"
        BorderColor="{StaticResource Gray-500}"
        CornerRadius="5"
        HasShadow="False"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Image
                Grid.Row="0"
                Margin="15"
                Aspect="AspectFit"
                BackgroundColor="Red"
                Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource BytesToImageSource}}" />

            <Label
                Grid.Row="1"
                Padding="15,0,15,15"
                FontSize="18"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                Text="{Binding Data}"
                TextColor="{StaticResource Gray-900}"
                VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </Frame>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: use AspectFill instead.  Fundamentally the problem is that your images are not the same size as the Image container

Comment: I tried AspectFill but with that, the image gets cropped either horizontally or vertically

Comment: Yes, that is how it works.  You are going to have to accept that your image will either be cropped/distorted/letterboxed as long as you are trying to fit images of unknown sizes into the same sized container.  There may be a better workaround, but that is the best suggestion I can provide off the top of my head.